# stop and restart a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, methods

I have to stop and restart a simple method that takes from 1 to 2 seconds to execute. How can this be accomplished? I have already tried `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]` but it works only with performselector after delay. I have also tried to create a new thread but it doesn't seem to work...

This is my method:

```
-(IBAction)MyMethod
{   
    NSLog(@"start");

    //Here is the code that takes time to execute. It regards UI intervention,graphic calculation, x and y position etc.

    NSLog(@"end");
}
```

I want this effect: one click on the linked `UIButton` and the method start (so print start log and end log). If I click the linked `UIButton` before the `NSLog` is printed, the method must stop. Is this possible?

Comment: So why don't you use `performSelector:afterDelay:` with a delay of 0?

Comment: cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget seems to cancel only the launch of a method.So i can't stop and restart execution if this method is already launched. For example in my code if i try to stop when execution is between the start and the end nslog with cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget the End nslog is always printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a background task. I would suggest subclassing and using a NSOperation and checking for `isCancelled` within the body of `main`. See Apple's documentation on using [NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i'v added a comment below,here is almost the same. The problem in this case is ui intervention,in a background thread i can't operate in ui (this is the large parte of execution time)

Comment: Right, so you'll need to post results/feedback to the main thread for display in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do this with threads what I usually do is dividing things into 3 sections:

- start.
- processing.
- finish.

And it looks like this:

```
-(void)start:(id)sender{
    //prepare everything and anything
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(processing:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)processing:(id)sender{
    //Perform all your calculations, you can't modify UI elements here

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finish:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)finish:(id)sender{
    //Wrap everything up and do any modifications to the UI
}
```

Now, to cancel this you could add maybe use:

> Cancels perform requests previously registered with
>   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:.

```
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument
```

Comment: i have tried to divide my graphic calculation and ui modification to fit your 3 section philosophy,the problem is that the great part of the execution (and so the great part of the execution time) regarding ui intervetion on main thread. So after division i have the same effect if i click my "Stop button" when i'm in -(void)finish:(id)sender method,i can't stop anything until the end of this block of code.